Finding the volume of the solid of revolution formed by revolving the region bounded by the given curves around the $x$-axis
Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed by revolving the region bounded by: $y=\sin x + \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $y=\cos x + \frac{\pi}{3}, x = \frac{\pi}{4}, x=\frac{9\pi}{4}$ around the x-axis.
My attempt:
$$
\pi \int _{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}\left(\sin x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2-\left(\cos x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx\ +\ \pi \ \int _{5\pi/4}^{9\pi/4}\left(\cos x+\frac{\pi \ }{3}\right)^2-\left(\sin x+\frac{\pi \ }{3}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx\ 
$$
Is there any way to prove that two area is equal to each other before applying integration? If yes, can I multiply the first integral by $2$?


where is the image? Anyways, to observe that the area would be same, draw the waveforms of both the curves.

If you can show that the two areas are equal, there is no problem in just calculating one and multiplying it by two.

Change variables $u=x+\pi$ and use the trigonometric identities then open the parentheses and some things will cancel out
